# Uncaught ReferenceError Fucntion is not defined in JavaScript and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am facing below issue while Onclick method in `html.erb` file in ruby on rails.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: modifyGroup is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (new:48141)
```

I have written a search and other methods in js file which all are working fine. But this method only not I am getting this error.

```
function modifyGroup() {
  var groupname = document.getElementById("groupname").value;
  var parametersname=document.getElementById("object_test").value;

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "/group/update_group",
    data: {
      groupname: groupname,
      parametersname: parametersname,
    },
    success: function(result) {
      if(result === 'false') {
        alert('Group Could not be Updated  !!!');
        return false;
      } else{
        alert('Group Updated successfully  !!!');
        window.location='/group/new';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: please Show full code

Comment: Please provide full code. Where are you calling modifyGroup() function?

Comment: i am calling  modifygroup() in below

Comment: <button name="butxton" type="button" onClick= "modifyGroup()" class="btn mx-auto btn-primary"  style="width: 200px;" id="update_group_btn">Update Group</button>

Comment: you calling `modifygroup` but function name is `modifyGroup`

Comment: Yes ModifyGroup() only.Copy paste mistake

Comment: Still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include the js files in your views by using the

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "filename_js", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

and please add your js file in assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( filename_js.js )
```

Then run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

And start your rails server

Comment: Welcome @AlexRoz